# How to fill input fields by using data from http

Tags: angular

I've built user list and filled it with relevant data from this source (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts). I displayed 'title' and 'body'. Then I've made "EDIT" buttons next to each user's title, so whenever you click it, two input fields are opened ('title' and 'body'). Now I want to fill these two input fields with default data from the source that I mentioned above. plus, if someone changes the text using inputs, the data should be changed. I tried to do it, but it is not working.

Here is HTML file:

```
<div class="forms container">
  <form #postForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="title" 
          name="title"  
          id="title" 
          type="text" 
          class="form-control"
          >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="10" 
        class="form-control"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is my component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/shared/posts.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {


  posts: any;

  constructor(private postService: PostService ,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(
      (posts: any) => this.posts = posts
    );
  }

}
```

And Here is my PostService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
}) 

export class PostService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getPosts() {
        return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you've written *any* code to handle the form?

This code:

```
    export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {


      posts: any;

      constructor(private postService: PostService ,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(
          (posts: any) => this.posts = posts
        );
      }
   }
```

Seems like just a copy of the code from your list component.

If you want your forms component to only work with one post, then the code needs to retrieve only the one post (not all of them).

And if your form is binding to:

```
[(ngModel)]="title"
```

and

```
[(ngModel)]="body"
```

Your component needs to expose those properties.

Here is an example of some code that displays a detail page. The code would be similar for your edit form:

https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Final

OR

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gettingstarted-deborahk

Answer (score 0):

You need to have properties named `title` and `body` in your component and assign values to them. Here is the sample on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-we5mfr